# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration.getClockProviderClassName()Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, spring-boot, blockchain, bean-validation, corda

Creating an cordaapp using cordapp-templete-java. 
While starting starter.java, we are getting "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration.getClockProviderClassName()Ljava/lang/String;" error.

**Starter.java:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Starter {
    /**
     * Starts our Spring Boot application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Starter.class);
        app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        app.setWebApplicationType(SERVLET);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir rootProject.file("config/dev")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Corda dependencies.
    compile "$corda_release_group:corda-rpc:$corda_release_version"

    // CorDapp dependencies.
    compile project(":cordapp-contracts-states")
    compile project(":cordapp")

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:$spring_boot_version") {
        exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"

    }
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa') {
        exclude(module: 'hibernate-validator')
    }

    /*compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }*/

    compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:${log4j_version}"
    compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:${log4j_version}"
    compile "org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:$slf4j_version"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api
  //  compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '1.0.0.GA'
  //  compile group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '8.0'
  //  implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.13.Final'





}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-parameters" // Required by Corda's serialisation framework.
}

springBoot {
    mainClassName = "com.template.webserver.Server"
}

task runTemplateClient(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'com.template.Client'
    args 'localhost:10006', 'user1', 'test'
}

task runTemplateServer(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'com.template.webserver.Starter'
    args '--server.port=10050', '--config.rpc.host=localhost', '--config.rpc.port=10006', '--config.rpc.username=user1', '--config.rpc.password=test'
}
```

**build.gradle:(main)**

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        corda_release_group = 'net.corda'
        corda_release_version = '3.3-corda'
        corda_gradle_plugins_version = '3.2.1'
        junit_version = '4.12'
        quasar_version = '0.7.9'
        spring_boot_version = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
        spring_boot_gradle_plugin_version = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
        slf4j_version = '1.7.25'
        log4j_version = '2.9.1'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:cordapp:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:cordformation:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:quasar-utils:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$spring_boot_gradle_plugin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordapp'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordformation'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils'

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir rootProject.file("config/dev")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile "junit:junit:$junit_version"

    // Corda dependencies.
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-node-api:$corda_release_version"
    cordaRuntime "$corda_release_group:corda:$corda_release_version"

    // CorDapp dependencies.
    cordapp project(":cordapp")
    cordapp project(":cordapp-contracts-states")

    cordaCompile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:${log4j_version}"
    cordaCompile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:${log4j_version}"
    cordaCompile "org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:$slf4j_version"

    compile group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '8.0'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.13.Final'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-parameters" // Required by Corda's serialisation framework.
}

task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    directory "./build/nodes"
    node {
        name "O=Notary,L=London,C=GB"
        notary = [validating : true]
        p2pPort 10002
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10003")
            adminAddress("localhost:10043")
        }
        cordapps = [
                "$project.group:cordapp-contracts-states:$project.version",
                "$project.group:cordapp:$project.version"
        ]
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
        p2pPort 10005
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10006")
            adminAddress("localhost:10046")
        }
        cordapps = [
                "$project.group:cordapp-contracts-states:$project.version",
                "$project.group:cordapp:$project.version"
        ]
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
        p2pPort 10008
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10009")
            adminAddress("localhost:10049")
        }
        cordapps = [
                "$project.group:cordapp-contracts-states:$project.version",
                "$project.group:cordapp:$project.version"
        ]
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
}
```

Please help in starting the spring boot server.

Answer (score 0):

Does your spring boot server start up if you remove all dependencies on corda?

It looks like you are excluding a specific version of hibernate-validator from the jpa-component, and then not adding it back to your spring-boot modules's dependencies.